# In angular, generate dynamic html content with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

My question is about generating dynamic html content with `ng-repeat` that contains multiple `ng-model` instances stored in an array.

But I get a syntax error for `{{` in `ng-model`.

Is it possible somehow?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12" ng-repeat="(key, antecedente) in antecedentes" >    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3">{{antecedente.name}}</label>
        <div class="col-md-1"> Si&nbsp;<input ng-model="historia.antecedentes[{{key}}].seleccionado" type="radio" value="S"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"> No&nbsp;<input ng-model="historia.antecedentes[{{key}}].seleccionado" type="radio" value="N"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">Observaciones </div>
        <div class="col-md-5"><input ng-model="historia.antecedentes[{{key}}].observacion" class="form-control"  type="text" value=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need curly braces around `key`, ng-model evaluates the expression/variable itself

```
 ng-model="historia.antecedentes[key].seleccionado"
```

Comment: Angular is brilliant. Thank you very much...friend !!  [A.B](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3680831/a-b)

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have a tag with `ng` in front of it, you don't have to have any curly braces, ever (except with ngSrc, wich whole purpose is to use curly braces inside a src). That's a good memory rule I think.

Comment: Yes, I know. Should've specified that. However, the ngSrc directive is special since it solves a problem with having curlybraces inside the src tag. So if you use ngSrc, you should know you CAN use curly braces inside there. It is, however, not necessary.

Comment: yes you can re arrange the words to clearify, still it's okay for us as we know things but can confuse beginners, just saying :)